# How can I add my own Resharper templates / snipets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-snippets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
<Header>
  <Title>cr</Title>
  <Shortcut>cr</Shortcut>
  <Description>Code snippet for Console.ReadLine</Description>
  <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
  <SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
  </SnippetTypes>
</Header>
<Snippet>
  <Declarations>
    <Literal Editable="false">
      <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
      <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
    </Literal>
  </Declarations>
  <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$SystemConsole$.ReadLine($end$);]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I have been created my own snippets in VS for C#. At this time I am using ReSharper, but my own snippets doesn's show to me like cw, prop or any other.

like this
[image]

Comment: Official reference is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html

Comment: I hope it's OK I took the liberty of editing your question title a little, mainly to include the word "templates", which is what this is called in Resharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio Menu go to Resharper - Tools - Template Explorer. Add your snippets there.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own templates under:

> Resharper > Tools > Template Explorer

In case usage is not immediately clear, here's an example. The following is a template I use for generating unit-tests for NUnit:

[image: My template for NUnit tests]

Click the dashed square icon to create a new template file (in a yellow circle below). Write your template-code in the window that opens up in the background, using **$** before and after words you want to be able to tab between.

Give your template a shortcut in the upper right corner, and save. You should now be able to use it.

The example above can be run using "<kbd>t</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>" or "<kbd>t</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>".

At that point, `DO_SOMETHING` will be selected for editing. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to and select `Test_logic`.